# Convert SQL result to hash with ID keys with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following array (SQL result):

```
[
  {:id => 1, :field1 => "one", :field2 => "two"},
  {:id => 2, :field1 => "one", :field2 => "two"},
  ...
]
```

What I want is:

```
{
  1 => {:field1 => "one", :field2 => "two"},
  2 => {:field1 => "one", :field2 => "two"},
  ...
}
```

Now I do like the following:

```
data = {}
result.each do |row|
  data[row[:id]] = {:field1 => row[:field1], :field2 => row[:field2]}
end
```

I'm absolutely sure that's wrong way. What is the best way to do it with Ruby? Is there are any snippet like **map** or something else?

Answer (score 6):

```
Hash[arr.map { |h| [h.delete(:id), h] }]
```

Answer (score 2):

One line :)

```
hash = arr.clone.each_with_object({}) { |e,res| res[e.delete(:id)] = e }
```

`clone` is for not destroying `arr` variable

Comment: One line? Can you do this with 0 lines?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe?

```
arr = [
  {:id => 1, :field1 => "one", :field2 => "two"},
  {:id => 2, :field1 => "one", :field2 => "two"}
]

hash = arr.each_with_object({}) do |el, memo|
  id = el.delete(:id)
  memo[id] = el
end

hash # => {1=>{:field1=>"one", :field2=>"two"}, 2=>{:field1=>"one", :field2=>"two"}}
```